# How to create a category and subcategory with rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, nested-sets, seed

I am trying to seed my rails 3 app, and hitting a problem. My Category table has the following fields:

string   "name"
integer  "position"
integer  "parent_id"

The parent_id is the id of another category, for nested_set.

Seeds.rb

```
Category.delete_all  
Category.create(:name => "Category 1",
              :position => 1,
              :parent_id => nil )

Category.create(:name => "Subcategory 1",
              :position => 1,
              :parent_id => 1 )
```

When I run

```
rake db:seed
```

I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
Couldn't find Category with id=1

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So, how do I create the Category first so the ID 1 will be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your version is not that it isn't being created in order, it's that the autoincrement doesn't reset so it isn't given an ID of 1.

Try:

```
Category.delete_all
first_category = Category.create(:name => "Category 1",
          :position => 1,
          :parent_id => nil )
second_category = Category.create(:name => "Subcategory 1",
          :position => 1,
          :parent_id => first_category.id )
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Can I continue to reference second_category.id third_category like that or how do I reference the the elements after first?

Comment: Ok I have thought about it and I understand that it doesn't autoincrement. So do I need to find the ID to reference the second or third element?

Comment: @ruevaughn Just assign the Category.create statement you are creating to a variable and then reference the id of that variable. The variable names I used are arbitrary.

Comment: Oops I didn't mean it doesn't autoincrement I meant the auto increment doesn't reset. Alright that makes sense thanks so much.

Comment: ah I see first_category.id was defined in the first_category = Category.create. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Category.delete_all  
parent = Category.create(:name => "Category 1",
              :position => 1,
              :parent_id => nil )

Category.create(:name => "Subcategory 1",
              :position => 1,
              :parent => parent )
```

Comment: I tried this answer and it works as well. Thanks. I chose the other answer because it had more of a description.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `:parent_id => Company.first` instead of `:parent_id => 1`